# how to get GeoLocation in Movilizer?

Tags: movilizer

In one of my use case, I need the current address(Geolocation) of my mobile device. How to get current Geolocation in Movilizer.

Anyone knows, Please let me know

Thanks,
Krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MEl, first of all you need to activate the continuous GPS capturing, using the method `startGPSCapturing()`. After it, you can use method `getGPSCoordinates()` that returns an array with this information:

```
{
    timestamp:
    {
        'ac' : accuracy in meters;
        'lt' : latitude;
        'lg' : longitude;
        's'  : source;
    };
};
```

This method returns the GPS location data from the queue as a two-dimensional array. The array includes the timestamp, the accuracy in meters, the latitude, the longitude, and the source of the GPS data.

Comment: can we get address like below in google maps along with lat/lang coordinates when we click on particular location in Movilizer

Ex: 
118-4-118-22 Atlantic Ave, South Richmond Hill, NY 11419, USA
40.693850, -73.828462